# How to layout my website to have 4 rows and 1 column?

Tags: css

I expect my page to be similar to [Yahoo](http://au.yahoo.com/?p=us) my expected result and the code are as following. I have tried different method but does not work. It should be in the middle and has the following sections.

**Expected result**

```
 50%            |LeftHeader                middleHeader                 RightHeade|    50% 
 50%            |                    50% Menu1 Menu2 Menu3 50%                    |    50%

 50%            |Content goes here ***********************************************|    50%
                |*****************************************************************|

 50%            |                   50% text of Footer goes here 50%              |    50%
```

These lines >> | show the border sections for example footer is that big but its text should be in center.

My code is as following

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <style>
    #wrapper {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width:50%;
    }
    #header {
        background-color:#faa;
        height:50px;
        font-size: 0;
    }
    #header > div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.3333%;
        font-size: 12pt;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #left {
        background-color:red;
        height:20px;
    }
    #middle {
        background-color:yellow;
        height:20px;
    }
    #right {
        background-color:green;
        height:20px;
    }
    #menu {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color:#faa;
        height: 20px;
        font-size: 0;
    }
    #menu > a {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 12pt;
        width: 33.333%
    }
    #content {
        top:50px;
        bottom:150px;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    #footer {
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#afa;
        height:150px;
    }
    #footer > div {
        margin-left: 50%;
    }
    </style

>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="left">
              left header
            </div>
            <div id="middle">
              middle
            </div>
            <div id="right">
              right header
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
         <a href="#">menu1</a>
         <a href="#">menu2</a>
         <a href="#">menu3</a>
      </div>
        <div id="content">
           content
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
           footer is here
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code (HTML, CSS)?

Comment: *"Does not work"* isn't very helpful. How doesn't it work? Also, I'd just use a grid framework. Google **css grid** and try out one of the many out there.

Comment: @Blender, whats the css grid I have not heard about that. Does not work means does not show what I need.

Comment: @albertxing question is updated. thanks

Comment: @JackRamzi your code doesn't seem complete. You have not yet attempted to add the columns in the content. Have you tried anything more than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a series of `<div>`s in `inline-block`, with `relative` positions and `margin: 0 auto` to center. The footer can be placed at the bottom with `position: absolute`, but you have to manually add the margins since absolute positioning doesn't support automatic centering.

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
#header {
    background-color:#faa;
    height:50px;
    font-size: 0;
}
#header > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333%;
    font-size: 12pt;
    height: 100%;
}
#left {
    background-color:red;
    height:20px;
}
#middle {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:20px;
}
#right {
    background-color:green;
    height:20px;
}
#menu {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#faa;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 0;
}
#menu > a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 33.333%
}
#content {
    top:50px;
    bottom:150px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 12.5%;
    width: 25%;
    background-color:#afa;
    height:150px;
}
```

See the Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8gmdk/

Comment: great thanks, but how change it to put the footer color wider and its text be in the middle of the footer? same for menu the pink color should be from the left bottom corner of leftheader to the right bottom corner of rightheader, also when I put the content there make the browser size smaller the content goes behind the footer and footer does not go a bit downer, you know the footer should be at the bottom of the page even if there is no content in the content section and if the content change the footer should go down to show the content

Comment: At Stackoverflow, we don't do your work for you. You have to present us with a problem, not with an assignment. There are many great HTML and CSS tutorials out there, and you should do suitable research before coming to stackoverflow with a question.

Comment: While I was waiting for you I have updated the code but I have two questions first is how to change my code so even when there is no content in content section the footer be at the bottom and the second question is that when I have updated the code each menu is on different section of menu but how to put them all in middle but keep the pink color that wide that it is now? thanks

Comment: Make the footer `position: fixed` instead of absolute. I'm not clear on what you want for the menus, but if you want the text at the center you can put `text-align: center`. If you want all the text *near* the center than put `text-align: left` for the rightmost menu item, `text-align: right` for the rightmost.

Comment: Thanks I have openned a new question you may find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628727/how-to-put-the-text-of-footer-in-center-and-the-links-of-menu-in-center-and-next

Answer (score 0):

To center all the content in the center of the screen you can use this:

```
body {
    width: 960px; /* define yours, you can also use max-width if you're going to use a fluid layout */
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: This is not good practice, to use `body` as `container/wrapper`.

Comment: @MiljanPuzović I use it here: www.santz.net, with no problems