# How to put the text of footer in center and the links of menu in center and next to each other?

Tags: css

I am expected result and the code are as following. My current style works but the problem is that the footer is too wide and and menu1.menu2,menu3 are not as illustrated blew,

**Expected result**

```
 50%            |LeftHeader                middleHeader                 RightHeade|    50% 
 50%            |                        Menu1 Menu2 Menu3                        |    50%

 50%            |Content goes here ***********************************************|    50%
                |*****************************************************************|

 50%            |                     text of Footer goes here                    |    50%
```

These lines >> | show the border sections for example footer is that big but its text should be in center.

My code is as following

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
#header {
    background-color:#faa;
    height:50px;
    font-size: 0;
}
#header > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333%;
    font-size: 12pt;
    height: 100%;
}
#left {
    background-color:red;
    height:20px;
}
#middle {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:20px;
}
#right {
    background-color:green;
    height:20px;
}
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#faa;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 0;
}
#menu > a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    width: 33.333%
}
#leftm {
    text-align: right;
}
#content {
    top:50px;
    bottom:150px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#afa;
    height:150px;
    position:fixed;
}
#footer > div {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="left">
          left header
        </div>
        <div id="middle">
          middle
        </div>
        <div id="right">
          right header
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
     <div id="leftm"><a href="#">menu1</a></div>
     <a href="#">menu2</a>
     <a href="#">menu3</a>
  </div>
    <div id="content">
vbcfxbfgbfcgbfg
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
      <div id="footertext">
        And here's the footer
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Result of my current code

```
 50%            |LeftHeader                middleHeader                 RightHeade|    50% 
 50%            |Menu1                         Menu2                       Menu3  |    50%

 50%            |Content goes here ***********************************************|    50%
                |*****************************************************************|

 50%            |                     text of Footer goes here                           |    50%
```

Comment: at least say something to know why I got negative vote :D strange people

Comment: I gave the negative vote for the reasons listed in my answer. Also, this is only a small advancement from his previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626146/how-to-layout-my-website-to-have-4-rows-and-1-column/15627670?noredirect=1#comment22171715_15627670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See updated code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8gmdk/1/).

I've wrapped the menu links in another div: `display: inline-block` with the `text-align` of the `#menu` set to `center`. This centers the three links.

The text in the footer is also centered through `text-align: center`.

Firstly, it is bad practice to open a new question asking the same thing. Secondly, avoid announcing "My code" unless you wrote the majority of it (this is not the case here). Thirdly, this question does not show much research effort as the footer text-align can easily be searched up.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- You can size the footer and still use `position:fixed` at `50%` as that's what the wrapper is.
- You had a few unnecessary tags (if I understand what you want)
- You were sizing your menu items by 33% when it seems like you didn't want that.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GwJvF/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="left">left header</div>
        <div id="middle">middle</div>
        <div id="right">right header</div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#">menu1</a>
        <a href="#">menu2</a>
        <a href="#">menu3</a>
    </div>
    <div id="content">vbcfxbfgbfcgbfg</div>
    <div id="footer">
        And here's the footer
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
#header {
    background-color:#faa;
    height:50px;
    font-size: 0;
}
#header > div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333%;
    font-size: 12pt;
    height: 100%;
}
#left {
    background-color:red;
    height:20px;
}
#middle {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:20px;
}
#right {
    background-color:green;
    height:20px;
}
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:#faa;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 0;
    text-align:center;
}
#menu > a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin:0 .5em;
}
#content {
    top:50px;
    bottom:150px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#footer {
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    background-color:#afa;
    height:150px;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by the goal. Does the footer need to be fixed? If yes, see example 2. Does the wrapper need to be height 100%?

Example 1:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/HSvW4/)

Example 2:
To fix the footer to the bottom of the window, add this to the footer:

```
width:50%;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
left:50%;
margin-left:-25%;
```