# How to align text at the center of a footer in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a [domain](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) in which I have made a page in HTML, CSS and Bootstrap 3.

If we scroll down at the footer, we can the text `Footer` is not in the center as shown below in the image (screenshot of the footer from the [domain](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/)). Its little bit up.

[image]

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the existing CSS codes so that the text `Footer` exactly comes at the center.

The CSS codes which I have used in the footer section is:

```
    /**** Footer START ****/

    .footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 12%;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .footer p {
        color: white;
        font-size: 2.25em;
    }
/**** Footer FINISH ****/
```

I have used the same CSS codes for the Header and its working perfectly as shown below in the design:

[image]

I do agree that `in the actual snippets and in the fiddle as well, its working quite fine` but I am not sure why its not working in the actual [domain](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/).

Comment: try adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the css for .footer

Comment: you need to add `.footer p { margin: 0; }`

Comment: @kpie doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put the text of footer in center and the links of menu in center and next to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628727/how-to-put-the-text-of-footer-in-center-and-the-links-of-menu-in-center-and-next)

Comment: @Vivek Singh I tried the CSS codes as mentioned in the link but for some reasons it didn't work.

Comment: @Vivek Singh I tried the same code as in the link but it still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet, it's working.

If you want vertically middle also, then try to give line-height in container that matches with height.

```css
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; 
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;  
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    justify-content: center;
}

.footer p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: doesn't effect much but it reduces the height instead. I kind of want the  `Footer` text to come at the center exactly in the header where the `Header` text is perfectly in the middle.

Comment: Still no change

Comment: @user5447339  check snippet its working.I didnt understood ur question.I think u want even vertically middle right?

Comment: I agree that its working well in the snippets but I am not sure why its not working well in the actual domain.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand but if you want from top to bottom in the middle:

```css
footer{
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color:white;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
footer>p{
  margin-top: calc(20px - 0.5em);
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p>Text</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: I agree that its working well in the snippets but I am not sure why its not working well in the actual domain.

Comment: Only other thing I would say try to say on css body{ font-size: 100%; }//which is 1em to every device some devices are different than others with pixels so it may bi different in snippet than on your screen...

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it worked...

```css
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12%;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.footer p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <p>Footer</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: for some reason it looks good for me at first but if I change tabs and come back it aligns the text at the bottom...